# Equivalent definitions for the disconnectedness of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

1. There exists a pair $A, B$ of disjoint nonempty subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$, neither of which contains a limit point of the other.
2. There exists a pair $U, V$ of disjoint nonempty open subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$.

I know the definition of a disconnected metric space $X$ is that there exist two non-empty subsets $X_1, X_2$ of $X$ such that 
$$
X=X_1 \cup X_2 \text{ and } X_1 \cap \overline{X_2}, \overline{X_1} \cap X_2=0
$$

How would I go about showing that the above two statements are equivalent?

Comment: When you say $A_1, A_2$, do you mean $X_1,X_2$?

Comment: @RolfHoyer Welp, sorry about that. Brainfart... Fixed. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2 \implies 1$ : $U,V$ disjoint nonempty open set whoes union is $X$..so $U^c=V$ so $V$ is closed so is $U$...so they contains all their limit points too.

$1\implies 2$ : $A$ contains all its limit point so $A$ is closed...same is true for $B$ and they are disjoint and their union is $X$...so $A^c=B$ so $B$ is open...so is $A$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I really should have known better.